# webpack-dev-server 4 with ngrok

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, ngrok

In older versions of webpack-dev-server (i.e 3 and below), we can simply expose webpack and webpack-dev-server's websock using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) tunnels by setting the value of `devServer.public`, as shown below:

```
// WDS v3
devServer: {
  public: 'react-tunnel.ngrok.io',
  // other webpack devServer config
}
```

This is particularly useful in developing apps in frameworks like React, as we can create a secure tunnel from the local machine, to a public URL to allow the web application to be easily tested.

However, in the latest versions of webpack-dev-server (v4), the `public` property has been replaced in favour `client.webSocketURL` object ([source](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md)). I am unable to find any resources to make this work with ngrok, as the websockets are not properly connected when I point the `devServer.client.webSocketURL.hostname` to my ngrok tunnel.

```
// WDS v4

devServer: {
  client: {
    webSocketURL: {
      hostname: 'react-tunnel.ngrok.io',
    },
  },
}
```

The above implementation is only a partial solution, as the websocket was not properly set up, thus it does not hot-reload.

Does anyone know what is the solution to this, such that ngrok will once again work well with webpack-dev-server?

Comment: up_V0te for for your beautiful question title!

Comment: Why not use ngrok to serve your localhost:3000? i guess it's the same thing, right?

Comment: This is actually a good question but the audience didn't get the use case. @TasosBu, he tries to get HMR working by having his site (ex: test.com) load his script test.com/script_built_by_webpack.js that hot loads from his ngrok tunnel

Answer (score 3):

You also need to provide port and protocol to make it work.
For example,

```json
devServer: {
  client: {
    webSocketURL: {
      hostname: 'react-tunnel.ngrok.io',
      port: 0,
      protocol: 'wss',
    },
  },
}
```

With above settings, your website may work in ngrok tunnel, but wont work in localhost.
To connect to the web socket regardless of url, you can set `webSocketURL` to `auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws`, which uses protocol, hostname, and port from browser. [doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#websocketurl)

This should fix hot-reloading problem as well.

```json
devServer: {
  client: {
    webSocketURL: 'auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws'
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the complete solution, but this works for me. You can put the hostname as localhost and some port as your needs. After running the dev-server, you could expose the port using `ngrok http {port}`.
Example: `ngrok http 3000`.

Answer (score 1):

I also stumbled onto the same issue and couldn't resolve it using any of the methods mentioned above. Took a little while before I stumbled across this simple solution, but this seems to work. Hope it helps:

```
devServer: {
  allowedHosts: [".ngrok.io"],
},
```